# Cancel in process wp remote get request in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a [semantic ui search](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html) bar which send request to wp on keyup and on wordpress side i am using [wp_remote_get](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/) to fetch api data.
The problem is when user type a query in search bar the pervious request is canceled in js side but wordpress request remains in process which cause a lot of time for user to see the results. 
I want a way to cancel the previous in process request when a new ajax request is received.